# Can't get primary DC up after restore

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, domain-controller, backup-restoration

Recently I have become the administrator of a Windows-server environment. Due to an error on the PDC, I decided to restore it from an old backup (a bit over a month old) - yeah I know now and I'm never making that mistake again.

After restoring I booted into Directory Services Restore Mode (DSRM) and deleted the logfiles from C:\Windows\NTDS, otherwise it wasn't able to do a normal boot.

Now the PDC aren't able to replicate from the SDC (Kerberos security error). I have read a bunch of posts an articles and as I understand, it's most likely due to shared secret inconsistency.

I have tried "netdom resetpwd" against SDC, but it raises this error: "The target account name is incorrect".

I can ping SDC from PDC and the time is the same on both machines.

Is it possible to demote the PDC and then promote the SDC to a new PDC?
At the moment the PDC are running some other roles, that I would rather not want to move to another server.

Thanks!